# Kotlin Kapt: java.lang.IllegalStateException: endPosTable already set

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, dagger-2, kapt

Trying to use the Kotlin maven plugin to build a kotlin application. Using Dagger 2 dependency injection framework. Get the following error when calling

`mvn clean compile package`

Can also be replicated by calling

`mvn clean package`

And then calling

`mvn package`

There seems to be a bug in maven 3 and java 8 that causes this, but I cannot find a work around for the kotlin maven plugin.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.1.3-2:kapt (kapt) on project process: Compilation failure
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: java.lang.IllegalStateException: endPosTable already set
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:57)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyzeAndGenerate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:344)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileBunchOfSources(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:226)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:200)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:55)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.exec(CLICompiler.java:182)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.KotlinCompileMojoBase.execCompiler(KotlinCompileMojoBase.java:236)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.K2JVMCompileMojo.execCompiler(K2JVMCompileMojo.java:184)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.K2JVMCompileMojo.execCompiler(K2JVMCompileMojo.java:43)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.KotlinCompileMojoBase.execute(KotlinCompileMojoBase.java:219)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: endPosTable already set
[ERROR]         at com.sun.tools.javac.util.DiagnosticSource.setEndPosTable(DiagnosticSource.java:136)
[ERROR]         at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Log.setEndPosTable(Log.java:350)
[ERROR]         at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:667)
[ERROR]         at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parseFiles(JavaCompiler.java:950)
[ERROR]         at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:892)
[ERROR]         at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:921)
[ERROR]         at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1187)
[ERROR]         at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
[ERROR]         at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:73)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:42)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:205)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:166)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:82)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:89)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:99)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:76)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:365)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:105)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:354)
[ERROR]         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyzeAndGenerate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:340)
[ERROR]         ... 30 more
```

Kotlin maven plugin and maven compile plugin are configured as follows:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>kapt</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>kapt</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                                    <version>${google.dagger.version}</version>
                                </annotationProcessorPath>
                            </annotationProcessorPaths>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-kapt</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-kapt</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                                    <version>${google.dagger.version}</version>
                                </annotationProcessorPath>
                            </annotationProcessorPaths>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>target/generated-sources/kapt/test</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <proc>none</proc>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Replacing default-compile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Replacing default-testCompile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Using:

```
Apache Maven 3.5.0
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Maven compiler plugin: 3.6.1
Kotlin maven plugin: 1.1.3-2
Dagger 2: 2.11
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: gradle kotlin-kapt plugin working fine